# XSL How to sum the node value based on condition

Tags: xml, xslt

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<books>
<book>
    <title fiction="true">Happy Potter</title>
    <author>J. K. Rowling et al</author>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book>
    <title fiction="true">The Hobbit</title>
    <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
    <price>25.99</price>
</book>

<book>
    <title fiction="true">Greater than 30</title>
    <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
    <price>31.99</price>
</book>

<book>
    <title fiction="false">Non-Fiction</title>
    <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
    <price>19.99</price>
</book>
```

**XSL FILE**

```
<xsl:for-each select="books/book">
<xsl:if test="(title[@fiction='false']) and (price &lt; 30)">
<span name="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></span><br/>
<span name="author"><xsl:value-of select="author"/></span><br/>
<span name="price"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></span><br/><br/>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>   

Total: <span name="total"><xsl:value-of select="sum(books/book/price)"/></span>
```

So my XSL will extract the data from XML based on the condition given.
When the `fiction=true` and the `price is < 30`. But I have no idea how to sum the total value. Any advise will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Use a predicate `sum(books/book[title[@fiction='false'] and price &lt; 30]/price)`.

Also you can shorten

```
<xsl:for-each select="books/book">
<xsl:if test="(title[@fiction='false']) and (price &lt; 30)">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="books/book[title[@fiction='false'] and price &lt; 30]">
```

Comment: Even better, define a variable `<xsl:variable name="eligible-books" select="/books/book[title/@fiction='false' and price &lt; 30]" />` and use it for both `<xsl:for-each select="$eligible-books">` and for `<xsl:value-of select="sum($eligible-books/price)"/>`.

Comment: I can't even shorten it and the sum, it goes to syntax error

Comment: Thanks Michael.hor257k. Your idea is work on me. Thanks for the advantage information.

Comment: @JackWong, I am not sure where you get a syntax error, the suggestion I made seems to work fine at http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZMC. Your input snippet is not complete, I had to add a closing tag for the root element.